# How to populate an array list in php with data from elements in XML file?

Tags: php, html, xml, xpath

Excerpt from mockup XML file:

```
<person>
   <i> 
     <book>
      <author id="mj">Margret Jane</author> 
      <author id="ms">Michael Scott</author>
      <author id="sj">Sarah Jane</author>
     </book>
   </i>
   <i> 
     <book>
      <author id="mj">Margret Jane</author> 
      <author id="tw>Tim Wind</author>
      <journal>ABC</journal>
     </book>
   </i>
   <i> 
     <article>
      <author id="mj">Margret Jane</author> 
      <author id="tw">Tim Wind</author>
      <journal>DEF</journal>
     </article>
   </i>
</person>
```

Say the XML file is 20x the size of this and there's over 100 variations of possible journals. Is there a way I can get all possible variations and store them in an array list? Is it possible by using XPath?

In the end I want to use it like this - where the user types a journal name and if it exists in the xml doc, the journal name will be printed:

```
<?php 
    $magazineSelect = $_GET['MagazineSelector'];
    if (in_array($magazineSelect, array("ABC", "DEF", "HIJ"))) {
        echo $magazineSelect;}
    else {
        echo "Unknown magazine - showing all results";}?>
```

Currently I have written out some of the possibilities by hand, but it's impossible to write out all of them.

Comment: If you want to make an array containing all journals names, why don't you use : `$data = $xml->xpath("//journal") `?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to save the data in a database, then search for it easily with MySQL Query.

You can use simplexml:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php